# Is there a standard medical fitness certificate format for applicants to European universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, health

I am from Southeast Asia and am applying to a university in Europe for a scholarship for a post graduate degree in management. The university is asking for a medical fitness certificate as part of this application.

The problem is that the university doesn't provide any kind of format for the medical fitness certificate. When I visited my doctor; as I am applying to a foreign university he recommended some kind of format.

I emailed the university to ask about this, but they did not respond yet.

So my question is, is there any kind of internationally recognized medical certificate format for this purpose? (If so, please provide a link.) Or can I have a simple letter on my doctor's letterhead stating my fitness of health?

Comment: It would probably also be helpful if you specify what you intend to study. Never heard of such a thing for engineering. If you want to study sports, it is much more understandable why they would ask for it. If the aim of the certificate is to make sure that scholarships are only handed to individuals with >=10 years of life expectence, a medical test result for professional vehicle steering may be suitable. The university will know best.

Comment: @DCTLib i am applying for a post graduate degree in management. Even i am confused why the university asked for a medical certificate but may be they want a guarantee that a student can complete their courses as higher education tends to increase stress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the right people to ask here are the staff at your local embassy. Certificates of good health, particularly in relation to European institutions, are more likely related to immigration requirements than university requirements. That will mean the embassy will be your best source of information about format. (In fact, there may only be specific doctors authorized to produce such certificates, and you may need to schedule an appointment with one of them, rather than obtain one from your personal primary care physician.)

Comment: In the US, universities in many (most?) states are bound by law to ensure that students meet specific immunization requirements, and so they require (at least) vaccination records from all students (both domestic and international). Some universities *also* require a basic medical history and/or a physical exam for incoming students.

Comment: Interesting point. I never had such inside the EU, but immigration did ask me for my medical insurance, so they can pass on the bills to my home country.